# How does WCF handle instancing and concurrency?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, concurrency

I try to understand how WCF handles instancing, concurrency and threading.

For example, if I configure the instance context mode to PerCall and concurrency mode to singe, every request creates a new instance of the WCF service. What does that mean related to the threads, which a created server side?

I guess that instancing and concurrency is not strong related to threading. Is it right that, to the given example, every request is queued by the "main" I/O ThreadPool to be executed by the worker thread? Or is every request creating a new instance and thread that executes this request?

Comment: What issue are you trying to fix?

Comment: I want to know how it handles instancing, concurrency and threading in order to understand WCF better. No special issue ;)

Comment: And what are you doing with WCF? Web services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I configure the instance context mode to PerCall and concurrency
>   mode to singe, every request creates a new instance of the WCF
>   service. What does that mean related to the threads, which a created
>   server side?

If you use Per-Call instancing then the service instances are all single threaded, as each incoming request is serviced by a new instance of the service. So specifying concurrency is not relevant in this scenario.

> I guess that instancing and concurrency is not strong related to
>   threading

I'm not sure how you arrive at this conclusion.

---

Addressing comments below this post:

> In a Per-Call mode, for each call we create an instance of the
>   service. If we are in a single thread mode, there is one thread
>   handling these instances so we serve requests in a sequential way

These two statements are contradictory. If we create a new instance per request, then the service does not handle multiple requests sequentially. It will create a new instance per request.

> (In PerCall mode) if the concurrency mode is multiple, there are many threads executing
>   the instances methods so we serve request in parallel way

This is not correct. Multiple requests will each be handled by their own service instance.

Handling a call in a service instance takes one thread. The call handling code may well be multi-threaded but this is internal to the service and WCF concurrency mode does not affect the execution of call handling code.

Other calls to the service will result in new instances of the service being created. So while you certainly *can* set concurrency mode to multiple, you will never get more than one thread handling requests to a service instance.

Therefore setting concurrency mode to multiple in per call instancing does not make any practical difference to the behavior of the service.

Comment: We can use the combination that we want depending on our context.
I note also that Per-Call instancing can be executed in multiple threads if you choose the concurrency mode "Multiple".

Comment: @hatem87 - concurrency mode has nothing to do with the multithreaded execution of the service call. It has to do with how many calls will be serviced by the service. Yes you can certainly *set* concurrency mode to multiple in a per-call scenario but it will not make any difference. The service instance will service at most one call and one call only. So you are incorrect in your assertion.

Comment: In a Per-Call mode, for each call we create an instance of the service. If we are in a single thread mode, there is one thread handling these instances so we serve requests in a sequential way. But if the concurrency mode is multiple, there are many threads executing the instances methods so we serve request in parallel way. I hope I described what happening in the right way :). Thanks.

Comment: @hatem87 - this is not correct. When you specify instance mode PerCall, you have an instance per call. Handling a call into the service instance takes one thread. The call handling code may well be multi-threaded but concurrency mode does not affect this. Other calls to the service will result in new instances of the service being spun up. So while you *can* set concurrency mode multiple, you will never get more than one thread being run in a service instance. Therefore it is not relevant.